# getGloss() Vs getDescription() in rita wordnet

Tags: wordnet

I'm using rita wordnet for my college project. I need to extract definitions of each and every word. When I am using `getGloss()`, a string with many one or more definitions is getting returned. Since I want only one definition per word, I turned to `getDescription()`.

So I'm just wondering that every word in rita wordnet contains its definition in `getDescription()` too or just in `getGloss()`??

Also, If you can please help me with this.. How to retrieve words from rita wordnet?? I can't find any method to retrieve words like `getWord()` or something like that??

Answer (score 2):

> So I'm just wondering that every word in rita wordnet contains its definition in getDescription() too or just in getGloss()??

getDescription() returns the definition;
getGloss() returns the definition plus an example sentence (gloss?).

Looks like getGloss() is a superset of getDescription() in RiTa.

Following are the implementations of those methods in `rita.RiWordNet.java`:

```
  /**
   * Returns full gloss for 1st sense of 'word' with 'pos' 
   */
  public String getGloss(String word, String pos)
  {
    Synset synset = getSynsetAtIndex(word, pos, 1);
    return getGloss(synset);
  }

  /**
   * Returns description for <code>word</code> with <code>pos</code> or null if
   * not found
   */
  public String getDescription(String word, String pos)
  {
    String gloss = getGloss(word, pos);
    return WordnetUtil.parseDescription(gloss);
  }
```

> How to retrieve words from rita wordnet??

Not sure what kinds of words you'd like to retrieve. If you were talking about word definition I believe you can do that with getAllGlosses() and getAllSynsets().
You may even write a getAllDescription() at your disposal.

Or check the reference of the RiTa library [here](https://rednoise.org/rita/reference/index.html) to look for the methods you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://rednoise.org/rita/reference/RiWordNet.php) shows that 'getDescription()' has been removed. You can use getGloss() or getExamples(), or getSynset(), as you need. Some examples:

`RiWordNet ww = new RiWordNet("/path/to/WordNet");
      System.out.println(Arrays.asList(rw.getSynset("dog", "n", 1)));
      System.out.println(Arrays.asList(rw.getAllGlosses("dog", "n")));
      System.out.println(Arrays.asList(rw.getGloss("dog", "n")));
      System.out.println(Arrays.asList(rw.getExamples("dog", "n")));`